# Strange movement when animate display none

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve an animation that displays a block that previously had `display: none;`.

I do a `@keyframes`, but it does an strange movement. My code is the following one:

**EDIT:**

You MUST expand the code because of `@media`.

I know is a little bit long, (TL-DR) but is the code I need to achieve my goal

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    min-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    min-height: 80px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    min-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    min-height: 80px;
  }
}
.news-general {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
.news-general .news-image {
  position: relative;
}
.news-general .news-image img {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.news-general .news-img-overlay {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.news-general .news-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 30px 60px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-info {
    padding-top: 130px;
    transition: padding-top 0.6s ease;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}
.news-general .news-date {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.news-general .news-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-general .news-summary {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-summary {
    color: white;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-summary {
    display: none;
  }
}
.news-general:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-img-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-date {
  color: #00FF00;
}
.news-general:hover .news-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: black;
}
.news-general:hover .news-summary {
  display: block;
  color: lightgrey;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down 0.6s ease;
  -moz-animation: slide-down 0.6s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-info {
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: padding-top 0.6s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-image {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-image img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-general">
    <div class="news-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582759788793-81043d629dd5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" alt="test">
        <div class="news-img-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
        <div class="news-date">February 27th, 2020</div>
        <div class="news-title">Foo Bar</div>
        <div class="news-summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nostra eget aptent, ligula molestie aliquam non massa hac placerat sem sed, semper urna ullamcorper morbi nullam rhoncus commodo natoque per. Molestie rutrum parturient tristique duis semper velit accumsan.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this problem? Why is this problem occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is related to the `slide-down` animation: if you set the `animation-fill-mode` property to `forwards` the jump effect disappears

```
animation: slide-down 0.6s ease forwards;
```

---

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    min-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    min-height: 80px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    min-height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    min-height: 80px;
  }
}
.news-general {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
.news-general .news-image {
  position: relative;
}
.news-general .news-image img {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.news-general .news-img-overlay {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.news-general .news-info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 30px 60px;
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-info {
    padding-top: 130px;
    transition: padding-top 0.6s ease;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-info {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
}
.news-general .news-date {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.news-general .news-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.news-general .news-summary {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: grey;
}
@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-summary {
    color: white;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  .news-general .news-summary {
    display: none;
  }
}
.news-general:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-img-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-date {
  color: #00FF00;
}
.news-general:hover .news-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: black;
}
.news-general:hover .news-summary {
  display: block;
  color: lightgrey;
  -webkit-animation: slide-down 0.6s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: slide-down 0.6s ease forwards;
}
.news-general:hover .news-info {
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: padding-top 0.6s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-image {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.news-general:hover .news-image img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-general">
    <div class="news-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582759788793-81043d629dd5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80" alt="test">
        <div class="news-img-overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="news-info">
        <div class="news-date">February 27th, 2020</div>
        <div class="news-title">Foo Bar</div>
        <div class="news-summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit nostra eget aptent, ligula molestie aliquam non massa hac placerat sem sed, semper urna ullamcorper morbi nullam rhoncus commodo natoque per. Molestie rutrum parturient tristique duis semper velit accumsan.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```